# date modified isn't null when creating record

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Normally in CakePHP, when you add a record with a form to a database table, CakePHP will automatically fill in the "created" field in de database with the current date & time. It works for my table called "attractions" (model "Attraction").

But now, strange things are happening. When I add a record for:

- model "AttractionProperty", table "attraction_properties"
- model "AttractionTypes", table "attraction_types"
- model "AttractionPropertyLink", table "attraction_properties_links"
- ...

... both the fields "created" and "modified" are filled in. I checked if the id of my model is set in the add action ($this->request->id), but it says "false". Is this a common problem or what could be the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `modified` field in your `Attraction` model as well? 
It is a feature to always set the `created` and `modified` field, if present. If you want to prevent it, add `'modified' => false` into your `$data` array, that you pass to `Model::create($data)` or `Model::save($data)`. 
Read more [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified)